# Is this the proper way to formulate kinetic energy of a 2 dimensional spring system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, spring

For a 2D system where a mass $m$ is coupled to a spring , with potential $V= \tfrac{1}{2}kr^2 $ , where $r$ is given by $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, would the kinetic energy be calculated as follows

$x=r\cos(\theta)$

$y=r\sin(\theta)$

$\Rightarrow x'=-r'\theta'\sin(\theta)$ and $y'=r'\theta'\cos(\theta)$

$\therefore T=\tfrac{1}{2}m(x')^2+\tfrac{1}{2}m(y')^2=\tfrac{1}{2}mr'^2\theta'^2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a quick way of finding the kinetic energy on spherical coordinates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x} &=& \dot{r}\cos\theta -\dot{\theta}r\sin\theta \\
\dot{y} &=& \dot{r}\sin\theta +\dot{\theta}r\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}

So that the kinetic energy is

\begin{eqnarray}
T &=& \frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}\cos\theta -\dot{\theta}r\sin\theta)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}\sin\theta +\dot{\theta}r\cos\theta)^2 \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2 (\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) + \frac{1}{2}r^2\dot{\theta}^2(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) + \dot{r}\dot{\theta}r (\sin\theta\cos\theta - \cos\theta\sin\theta) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Small typo in $\theta$ derivative in expression for $\dot{y}$.